# Using react 0.59 but hooks aren't working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my app I am using the react version 16.12.0 (latest stable version). The react-native is in the 0.59.10.

But always when I try to use react hooks (as useEffect, useState, etc.) I am getting an error that says that `useState` is undefined, so I can not use it.

I tried to console.log the useState and got undefined. What makes no sense, since the react version already have hooks inside it.

When I run `react-native info` I get it:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
      Memory: 79.72 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.11.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 5.6.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
      Xcode: 11.2.1/11B500 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: ^16.12.0 => 16.12.0
      react-native: ^0.59.5 => 0.59.10
```

Comment: `I am getting an error.` what error? Please add the error to your answer

Comment: Updated there, basically it says that the useEffect is undefined. Have no idea why.

Comment: Can you update the code segment here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why that happens is because you are using a mismatch version of react and react native.

If you take a look at the [changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed-8) it says that the react version is at `16.8.3` so you should change to that instead of using the latest react version.

Or just upgrade react native to the lastest to match your react version.

You can also see that the [latest version](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed) of react native isn't using the latest version of react.

Comment: Update the react-native is not an option by this time, it took me some days to update from the version I got it. But I'm planning to do it as soon as possible, when have time to do it.

Comment: Is there a way to find easily this versions match? I'm getting the exactly same problem with react-redux hooks now, but i don't know how to look the version that match it in an easy way.